# Understanding a vimscript function

Tags: vimscript, visual-mode

I have the following function in a vim plugin:

```
fu! HOLSelect(l,r)
  let l:cursor = getpos(".")
  if search(a:l,"Wbc") == 0
    return
  endif
  normal v
  if search(a:r,"W") == 0
    normal <ESC>
    call setpos('.', l:cursor)
    return
  endif
  call search(a:r,"ce")
endf
```

I am trying to understand it without a deep vimscript knowledge.

When it is called the following way:

```
nn <silent> <LocalLeader>a :call HOLSelect('Triviality\\|Theorem','Proof')<CR>-Vo+
```

It visually selects the region between (not including) the lines `Triviality` or `Theorem` and `Proof`. These stand on their own in the file:

```
Theorem
  ∀ P. P ==> P
Proof
    rw []
```

I see two `search` calls but it is not clear how it selects the region between the two endpoints.

Could you explain how this function selects the region's two endpoints between `Theorem` and `Proof` and passes it on?

Comment: *3* search calls, and one `normal v` (that should really be `normal!` for portability though)

Comment: Probably worth noting for future readers that [`:normal <ESC>` is a bug.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/29673/343)

Comment: Seems like an overly complicated way to go about things. `search()` returns line number. Store the first line number in variable `start` and the second in `end` and then you could just do `exe start+1 | exe "normal V" | exe end-1` or equivalent....to name just the first idea that came to mind. But perhaps I'm missing some nuance or something not shown here.

Comment: I meant, `"normal! V"`, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tricky bits here so lets break this down into components.

```
search(a:l,"Wbc")
```

This will search for the pattern backwards (`b` flag). It uses the `W` to prevent wrapping around the file and `c` to accept a search at the current position. This will in affect find the beginning of the pattern and move the cursor there. e.g. `Theorem` in this case with the cursor on the `T`

```
search(a:r,"W")
```

This will search for the pattern forwards and put the cursor at the start of the match. The `W` flag to prevent wrapping around the file. e.g. `Proof` in this case with the cursor on the `P`.

```
call search(a:r,"ce")
```

This will move the cursor to the end of a match (`e` flag) and accept a match at the current position (`c` flag). e.g. Set the cursor on top of the `f` in `Proof`

With these searches together we can find the start and the end of the patterns. It uses `:normal v` to make a visual selection.

The next trick is how it selects the part in-between the matches. The mapping is what does this via `-Vo+`

- `-` go to the start of the previous line
- `V` use visual-line mode
- `o` switch to the other end of the visual selection. The start in this case
- `+` go the the start of the next line

The rest of the code and flow control is designed to handle errors when a pattern is not found

Comment: What made this hard to understand was that it had used visual selection twice, once in the function and once after the function.